# How to efficiently manage third-party dependencies with p2-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, eclipse-rcp

In order to manage third-party dependencies in an Eclipse RCP application (built with Tycho) I am using the p2-maven-plugin and Jetty to convert maven central artifacts to bundles and make them available as a P2 repository in my Target definition file. My setup and workflow is as follows :

- Add the dependency in the artifacts section of the p2-maven-plugin.
- run the goal p2:site which rebuild the entire site.
- run jetty.
- Reload the Target.
- And now my dependency is available in the dependency section of the Manifest file.

So I have 3 questions:

- Each time I want to add a new dependency I have to rebuild the site and restart Jetty, is there a way to just update the repository by adding new dependencies referred in the pom ?
- Would the following setup be suitable in the context of company with multiple projects :

  - Create a (specific third-party) remote P2 repository for each project and configure the target definition of the project accordingly.
  - When a team member wants a third-party library, he can use p2-maven-plugin to generate bundles, push them in the remote repository and clean the artifact section of the pom.

To conclude, how do you manage third-party dependencies in your team ?

Comment: what do you mean wit "clean the artifact section of the pom."?

Comment: I mean that the dependency specified in the artifact section of the p2-maven-plugin configuration can be removed because bundles are now present in the remote repository and the dependency is specified somewhere in a manifest file.

Comment: In fact what I want is to tell p2-maven-plugin to not consider artifacts that are already in the target repository, but I don't know how to do that ? And maybe something more easier that running a local jetty instance, such as deploy bundles in the .m2 folder so that remote repository will be not necessary and Tycho could resolve target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the problem is, when you build a p2 site  metadata will be generated also "context.xml" and "artifact.xml" containing the bundels inforamtion. these metadata used by the p2 resolver for resolvin the bundles. so i think without rebuilding the site it will be a hard way to get your p2 repo updated.

  my suggestion: the clearst way to go since you working in a team is to have a standalone Repository (nexus, jetty, tomcat...) for all third party dependencies ( you may use the [category.xml](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/category.xml)).

  deploying the recreated p2 is not a big deal you can use `wagon-maven-plugin` in the same pom creating your site and bind it to the deploy phase, so with `mvn clean deploy` you get your repository created and deployed

Example:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
        <artifactId>p2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-cli</id>
                <configuration>
                    <artifacts>
                        <!-- specify your depencies here -->
                        <!-- groupId:artifactId:version -->
                        <artifact><id>commons-io:commons-io:2.1</id></artifact>
                        <artifact><id>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4</id></artifact>
                        <artifact><id>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.5</id></artifact>
                        <artifact><id>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6</id></artifact>
                        <artifact><id>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1</id></artifact>
                    </artifacts>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>upload-repo</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>upload</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <fromDir>${project.build.directory}/repository/</fromDir>
                    <includes>*/**</includes>
                    <serverId>my-p2-repository</serverId>
                    <url>dav:http://mycompany.com/../content/repositories</url>
                    <toDir>thirdparty-p2-repository</toDir>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

```
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>my-p2-repository</id>
            <url>dav:http://mycompany.com/../content/repositories</url>
        </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Note: The ID of the URL in the distributionManagement section of your pom needs to match the ID of a server section in your settings.xml file.

add the server in settings.xml:

```
<server>
 <id>my-p2-repository</id>
 <username>...</username>
 <password>...</password>
</server>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: So if I understand there is no way to tell p2-maven-plugin to handle only artifacts which are not already bundled and to update a p2 repo with new one. In any case, your suggestion seems good to skip the Jetty local instance, Thanks !